# Generating a random number from the array

Tags: java, arrays, random

Suppose there is an array :

```
int arr[] = {0,1,2}
```

Is there a way I can generate a random number out of `0,1,2` *(i.e from the array)* ?

Comment: you mean pick randomy one of these numbers witch the array is holding ?

Comment: @A4L yeah I mean the same

Comment: QuadroQ explains how, Sano shows how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
    import java.util.Random;

    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println(arr[random.nextInt(arr.length)]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. You should generate a number between 0 and arr.length-1, round it to a int number and then take the arr[your_random_number] element.

```
int random_index = (int) round(Math.random() * (arr.length - 1));
```

then your element would be arr[random_index]

Comment: what do you mean by repeated?

Comment: This is *random*, but not *fair*, as the rounding causes `0` and `arr.length - 1` to both occur roughly half as often as any other number. Better to use `aRandom.nextInt(arr.length)` or `(int) (Math.random() * arr.length)`

Comment: yeah, might be ... i'm not really that familiar with the statistical problems random might have.

Comment: The standard way to do this is (int) (Math.random()*arr.length) - this gives us exactly what we want with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique element each time from the array then try this:

```
Integer arr[] = {0,1,2}
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
for(int unique: ar)
   System.out.println(unique);
```

Shuffle method of Collections  will randomly shuffle the given array .

Comment: this won't work as you expect for a `int[]`, only for a `Integer[]`. With `arr` being `int[]` this `Arrays.asList(arr)` will return a list of length 1, which makes no sense shuffling...

Comment: @jlordo Using Random can generate same number more than once...yes?

Comment: this is not what the questioner wants, this will alter the list placing each element randomly somewhere else.

Comment: @A4L: No, it is no placing each element somewhere else, it does nothing, because `arr` is a `int[]`. I'll post some code in a minute.

Comment: Look at this [http://ideone.com/kCK0TE](http://ideone.com/kCK0TE) for `int[]` and this [http://ideone.com/u8tjnZ](http://ideone.com/u8tjnZ) for `Integer[]`. and see the difference.

Comment: @jlordo, my comment was based on `Integer[]` as `Arrays.asList(new int[]{0,1,2})` wont give that what one expects, it instead makes a list of int arrays with one element, while actually you want a list with tree integers :)

Comment: @A4L: I know, see the first comment under this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will pick a number randomly out of the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int arr[] = {0,1,2};
    System.out.println(arr[(int)(Math.random()*arr.length)]);
}
```